# Alternative to cross database trigger in Azure?

Tags: database, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a website that does two things:

1)  It allows users to select a group from the dropdown menu and push a button to run a report on a group that already exists in our database.

2)  If a group is not already in the group list, a second page allows the user to input some group information to our database (with the idea that they could then run a report on that group.

When the website coder created the website, he put the dropdown menu options into one database and has the collected group information going into another.

Problem: 
Once the new group information has been collected, I need to update the drop down table in the other database to include the name of the new group.

The easiest fix would probably be to have the website update both tables, but we not longer have the services of the guy who coded the website and I need to get this fixed.  So, I want to fix this on the database side.

I was thinking I could do that with an insert trigger, however, other strings state that cross-database triggers aren't a kosher thing to do.

Further complicating the matter, our databases are both hosted on Microsoft Azure. I found a post about doing a select from two statements on Azure and am trying to work through it to create a cross-database query right now.  I am still unsure how I will solve the problem of needing data in both databases though.

What can I do?

Comment: I think your path of least resistance would be a code-based solution, possibly using Azure Functions that runs periodically to poll the table for change and then update the other database. That's far from an ideal solution but it should be up and running pretty quickly requiring minimal code and no changes to your current software. I know this isn't quite what you're asking for but I'm not entirely sure what your capabilities are, and cross-db queries aren't really possible in SQL Azure for many reasons.

Comment: FYI, I may have been incorrect. A feature that's new to me with the external data sources is described in one of the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26171872/sql-azure-cross-database-queries?rq=1

Comment: You can also try Azure Logic Apps other than Functions, benefit : Azure will less charge you for Logic Apps triggers, But at least you should have access to your both the databases.

Comment: recently,there were annoucments by Scott Guthrie,anouncing many features like  cross database querying,sqlagent,clr and service broker support,this may arrive in next coming months.But as of now the answer to your question is `no`